# MAC equivalent - user name & appdata

Tags: macos, mac, operating-systems, environment-variables, matlab

I have a couple of questions:

1. On PC I can get the username from the environment variable `USERNAME` and on LINUX it is `USER` - what the MAC equivalent?
2. The users local area on windows can be found via the registry (or equivalent) , on LINUX you type `~` at the command prompt - what is the MAC equivalent?

Note I would like to extract these from environment variables if possible (from code).

e.g.  I want to create a file in the users home area on MAC > how would I build the following variable -:

This is what I think it is - can anyone confirm (note I dont currently have a MAC in front of me to test it...)

```
% e.g.
userName = getenv ( 'USER' );  
userLocalArea = '~/Library/Preferences/';
filename = fullfile ( userLocalArea, userName );
```

In the end the language I am doing this in is Matlab - but its a pretty general question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need the user name to put something in their home structure.

Simply starting `~/` will direct it to their home, so `~/Library/` will go to the current user's
`[Boot Drive]/Users/[User Name]/Library/`.

If you need to install for  all users, use `/Library/` instead.

I guess it's the equivalent of Windows' `%appdata%/`

If you really need the name & folder …

```
userName=$(logname)   
    or userName=$(user)
userLocalArea=$(home)
```

After tests, there seems to be some inconsistency - these work better in Terminal… as some calls don't appear to work in both upper & lower case, it looks like upper case is a safer 'rule'. Someone smarter than me will have to fill in why some work in brackets & some don't.

```
userName=$LOGNAME
    or userName=$USER
userLocalArea=$HOME
```

That will get their shortname & home folder

Not sure how to get longname without osascript…

`osascript -e "long user name of (system info)"`

This all assumes your install is being done by the currently logged user.

Comment: Hi thanks - I want to extract the [USER NAME] for other reasons than obtaining the home structure.  If I follow it is the environment variable `logname' or 'user'  (is it case sensitive?)

Comment: It's not normally something I play in, so just doing some tests which seem a bit confusing to me, though idk the underlying reason… echo $(logname) works upper or lower; echo $(user) doesn't work at all, neither does echo $logname but echo $LOGNAME does; echo $user works either case; echo $(home) or echo$(HOME) doesn't work, echo $home doesn't, yet echo $HOME does work.

Comment: I tweaked the answer - I really am not sure why one syntax works for one call yet not another.